# Sed: search and replace a patten with special characters which has a arbitrary string in between

Tags: sed, replace, html, special-characters, whitespace

I have a load of nfo files which I want to make some global substitutions for some values within each file

e.g.

```
   a.nfo has the value <set>Tonight&apos;s Menu ( June 2012 )</set>
   b.nfo has the value <set>Tonight&apos;s Menu ( April 2012 )</set>
   c.nfo has the value <set>Speciel Menu ( April 2012 )</set>
```

Which I want to make all of them have the same value.

```
   a.nfo has the value <set>Tonight&apos;s Menu</set>
   b.nfo has the value <set>Tonight&apos;s Menu</set>
   c.nfo has the value <set>Tonight&apos;s Menu</set>
```

I've got this code which is almost working but not quite

```
    find -name '*.nfo' -print -exec sed -i.bak "s@\(<set>\).*\(</set>\)@\1Tonight&apos;s Menu\2@" {} \;
```

at the moment the result I get is

```
      <set>Tonight<set>Tonight&apos;s Menu ( June 2012 )</set>apos;s Menu</set>
```

Comment: Please show us the actual file. Do all lines have `<set>`? Only some? Do you want to change all cases of `<set>`?

Answer (score 2):

Matching the text between `<set>` and the following `<`. Backslash is required to take away the special meaning of `&` for sed.

```
 sed 's/<set>.*</<set>Tonight\&apos;s Menu</' yourfile
```